# How to chain observables?

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

I need to chain two observables, the second depends on the first.
So what I have is:

Observable 1 -> petition returns Observable<TvShow>

```
//kotlin
fun getTvShow(): Observable<TvShow> {
    return retrofitPetitionGetShow()...
}
//java
Observable<TvShow> getTvShow(){
    return retrofitPetitionGetShow()...
}
```

Observable 2 -> returns Single<List<Season>>

```
Observable.range(1, TvShow.totalSeasons)
            .flatMap { seasonNumber: Int ->
                retrofitPetitionGetSeason(seasonNumber)....
            }.toList()
```

What I need is the result of the second observable (List<Season>) to be added to the TvShow object `TvShow.setList(List<Season>)` and then return it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're saying. but I think what you are looking for is the zip function

Comment: @mohsen but can I use zip if the petition for the second observable needs as parameter a objectA property? Sorry English is not my first language

Comment: Is observable1 a makePetition method? What is obeservable2? Try to adjust the question and code snippet/description

Comment: @mslowiak I edited the question with (I think) a less confusing example.

Comment: zip is used to combine multiple observables and decide what to do when both are done. can't you simply add it to your list in onSucces() or onNext()?

Comment: @mohsen but I can't make a zip if the second petition depends on the first petition, right?

Comment: @wilkin25 in the second observable there is `TvShow.totalSeasons`. That value is taken from first observable right?

Comment: @mslowiak yes, exactly

Comment: @wilkin25 posted an answer below, please take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on provided information in comments you can try with the following code (it is Java code but it should be easy to convert that to Kotlin):

```
private Observable<TvShow> getTvShow() {
    return retrofitPetitionGetShow();
}

private Single<List<Season>> getSeasons(TvShow tvShow) {
    return Observable.range(1, tvShow.getTotalSeasons())
            .flatMap(seasonNumber -> retrofitPetitionGetSeason(seasonNumber))
            .toList();
}

public Observable<TvShow> chainObservables() {
    return getTvShow()
            .flatMap(tvShow -> getSeasons(tvShow).map(tvShow::withSeasons).toObservable());
}
```

**IMPORTANT!**

In reactive/functional way you should not modify objects, but create the new one (in your case, there is an update of tvShow with seasons list). There is a `tvShow::withSeasons` method reference which is implemented in this way:

```
public TvShow withSeasons(List<Season> seasons) {
        return this.seasons == seasons ? this : new TvShow(this.name, this.totalSeasons, seasons);
    }
```